# How can I create 1000 files that I can use to test a script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, perl, scripting

I would like to create 1000+ text files with some text to test a script, how to create this much if text files at a go using shell script or Perl. Please could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create one text file? Can you devise a scheme to generate file names, eg. file0001, file002? Can you write a for loop to do those two tasks. At what point do you get stuck?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for i in {0001..1000}
do
  echo "some text" > "file_${i}.txt"
done
```

or  if you want to use Python <2.6

```
for x in range(1000):
    open("file%03d.txt" % x,"w").write("some text")
```

Comment: Your filenames in the Bash version will be 10 through 1000999. I think you mean `echo "some text" > file$file`

Comment: The first option requires Bash 4 to make use of the padding. In earlier versions, you can specify leading zeros, but they won't appear in the result.

Answer (score 9):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
seq 1 1000 | split -l 1 -a 3 -d - file
```

Above will create 1000 files with each file having a number from 1 to 1000. The files will be named from `file000` to `file999`.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $i (1..1000) {
   open(my $out,">",sprintf("file%04d",$i));
   print $out "some text\n";
   close $out;
}
```

Why the first 2 lines? Because they are good practice so I use them even in 1-shot programs like these.

Regards,
Offer

Comment: ... or you could just `use autodie;`

Answer (score 3):

For variety:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

write_file $_, "$_\n" for map sprintf('file%04d.txt', $_), 1 .. 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for suf in $(seq -w 1000)
do
        cat << EOF > myfile.$suf
        this is my text file
        there are many like it
        but this one is mine.
EOF
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take any big file that has more than 1000 bytes (for 1000 files with content). There are lots of them on your computer. Then do (for example):

```
split -n 1000 /usr/bin/firefox
```

This is instantly fast.

Or a bigger file:

```
split -n 10000 /usr/bin/cat
```

This took only **0.253 seconds** for creating 10000 files.

For 100k files:

```
split -n 100000 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Only **1.974 seconds** for 100k files with about 5 bytes each.

**If you only want files with text**, look at your /etc directory. Create one million text files with almost *random* text:

```
split -n 1000000 /etc/gconf/schemas/gnome-terminal.schemas
```

20.203 seconds for 1M files with about 2 bytes each. If you divide this big file in only 10k parts it only takes 0.220 seconds and each file has 256 bytes of text.

Comment: The only quibble can be 'the files won't be text files'.  I have an archaic version of GNU `split` that doesn't recognize `-n`; the BSD (Mac OS X) version of it does not recognize it either.  I just need to upgrade my CoreUtils installation.

Comment: Ok, that is true. If you want a million small text files, just use a big text file as input. There are enough on your computer. For example /etc/gconf/schemas/gnome-terminal.schemas which has 2.6 MB if you want a very big one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in shell or perl but in python would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

for i in xrange(1000):
    with open('file%0.3d' %i,'w') as fd:
        fd.write('some text')
```

I think is pretty straightforward what it does.

Comment: I tried your script, but I'm getting an error:

./crea.py:4: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "./crea.py", line 4
    with open('file%0.3d' %i, 'w') as fd:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try from __future__ import with_statement

Comment: That would be `from __future__ import with_statement` (the system ate the underscores in **ghostdog74's** comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can use only Bash with no externals and still be able to pad the numbers so the filenames sort properly (if needed):

```
read -r -d '' text << 'EOF'
Some text for
my files
EOF

for i in {1..1000}
do
    printf -v filename "file%04d" "$i"
    echo "$text" > "$filename"
done
```

Bash 4 can do it like this:

```
for filename in file{0001..1000}; do echo $text > $filename; done
```

Both versions produce filenames like "file0001" and "file1000".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short command-line Perl program.

```
perl -E'say $_ $_ for grep {open $_, ">f$_"} 1..1000'
```